# Object persistance through frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I got an object called `MemoryCards` which consists of 3 frames.
Frame 1 is Language1, Frame 2 is Language2 and Frame 3 is a neutral backside.

Frames 1 and 2 contain a textfield with a word in the language in it.

Now I create two memory cards for each word like this:

```
        for (var key:String in dict) 
        {
            var val:String = dict[key];

            var tileLat:MemoryCards = new MemoryCards();
            var tileEng:MemoryCards = new MemoryCards();

            tileLat.gotoAndStop(1);
            tileEng.gotoAndStop(2);

            TextField(tileLat.getChildAt(1)).text = key;
            tileLat.latin = key;
            tileLat.front = 1; // front frame

            TextField(tileEng.getChildAt(1)).text = val;
            tileEng.latin = key;
            tileEng.front = 2;

            cards.push(tileLat);
            cards.push(tileGer);

        }
```

When I use trace now, the textbox have the correct values assigned. But for the start of the game I need to flip those tiles over by setting them to frame 3.

My problem now is, that when I go back to Frame 1 or 2 the TextFields have reset to the default value.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Make the tiles data-driven and let them worry about setting the text in the textfields when they have them.

Comment: I'm quite new to flash. Do you mean I should use getters and setters?
Or do you mean I should set the text when the frame is switched?

Comment: Getters and setters (in the Tile MC's base Class) are how I would handle it. http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html

Comment: Okay, but just for educational purposes: is there a way to do it by keeping the text from resetting?

Comment: No, because the text doesn't reset. The Flash Player is creating a new instance for you whenever you enter the frame with the TextField, and destroying it when you leave.